# Is it possible to skip main mode for IPSec communication on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, firewall, ipsec

On Linux, after registered several SAs (Security Associations) between a pair of Linux host, I can create communication between those two Linux hosts, i.e, communicate with ESP packets.

But on Windows, It seems that there are two phase to create IPSec communications, i.e, in first phase, named MainMode, authentication and key exchanging is necessary, and in second phase, named Quickmode, ESP packets were sent/received for data communications.

By some constraints, I need to skip the first phase, i.e, use the same behaviors as on Linux, Is it possible to do that? If the answer is yes? How can I configure it?